# How to remove the "title" attribute that the CKEditor 4 add automatically on inline editing?

Tags: ckeditor, title, inline-editing

When using CKEditor 4 Inline Editing on a object the CKEditor add a "Title" attribute that include
a text and the object id.

e.g. In the CKEditor inline example we can see the next code:

```
<h2 id="inline-sampleTitle" title="Rich Text Editor, inline-sampleTitle"....>CKEditor<br>Goes Inline!</h2>
```

I like to remove the "title" attribute because i do not like the user to see it (my id is more complicated :) ).

Note: I was trying to remove it manually after the CKEditor create it using jQuery "removeAttr" function but this
solution is not really good for me because in IE browsers the user still see it in the first time and it will
remove only after the user mouse out from  the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the title ckeditor sets for inline instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502142/how-can-i-change-the-title-ckeditor-sets-for-inline-instances)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CKEDITOR.config.title = false;

For More Details Visit [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets)

Comment: You may want to add more detail to your answer; it is not very clear as it is now.

Comment: Reference link just Updated.

Comment: The link in the answer is useless; here's the link to the property itself: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-title

Answer (score 1):

You can find here some details: [How can I change the title ckeditor sets for inline instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502142/how-can-i-change-the-title-ckeditor-sets-for-inline-instances/14548739#14548739)

Unfortunately, you cannot change it without modifying the code. I reported ticket for this http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10042

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for them to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270613/2148773 - looks like you can manually set the "title" attribute of the editor element to override the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

in your config

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
    config.title="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor fix it in version 4.2 so we can remove this fix now :)
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10042

Answer (score 0):

You can put in ckeditor config object function that will delete the title after editor is initialized:

```
on: {       
        instanceReady: function(event){
            $(event.editor.element.$).attr('title','');
        },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in order to delete the title on every CKEDITOR will be created.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',function(event){$(event.editor.element.$).attr('title','');});
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this in my codeigniter view page and it works for me.
also i used my own custom tooltip for my users.

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'ckeditor' );
CKEDITOR.config.title = false; // or you can use own custom tooltip message.
```

thanks
Braham Dev Yadav

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using

```
CKEDITOR.config.title = false;
```

but it still persist showing title.

After some research, what I done is:

1.Go to ~/ckeditor/lang/en-gb.js remove out 'editorHelp' value

2.Assign language and title, same as below:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.language="en-gb";
config.title="Put your title here"; //cannot put blank, it will display "null"
```